# Sphinx not like

Tags: sphinx

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой нужно реальзовать что-то на подобии NOT LIKE с помощью Sphinx возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сфинксе есть [оператор NOT](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.1/boolean-syntax.html) для указания минус слов.  Для этого перед минус словом нужно поставить - или !

Comment: пробовал такой запрос (samsung !s4) но он мне возвращает где встречается слово samsung и s4, SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY), SetRankingMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE)

Comment: извеняюсь все правильно работает моя ошибка большое спасибо